# How does the perpendicular chords affect this circle geometry question?

Tags: geometry

guys, I have worked through this problem although I found possible answers but I am still unsure. 
Question: PQ and RS are two perpendicular chords of a circle, centred at O of radius 5cm, intersecting at K. Each chord is 8cm long, find the length of OK.

My workings: 
RS=8, PQ=8 PM(for midpoint) = MQ (line from centre to mid-pt chord)
$PO^2=PM^2 + MO^2$ (Phytagoras), $5^2=4^2 + MO^2$, $3cm$ = MO

Now, this is the part where I am stuck, but I do know that in order to find OK I need Pythagoras. Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend $OM$ to $N$ on the circle, and let the tangent at $N$ meet $SR$ extended at $L$.

Then by Euclid, *Elements III, 36*$$NL^2=LR\cdot LS$$[image: length of OK]And since$$RS=8$$and$$LR=\frac{10-8}{2}=1$$then$$LN^2=1\cdot 9$$and$$LN=KM=3$$But equal chords in a circle are equidistant from the center. Therefore$$OM=KM=3$$and by Pythagoras$$OK=\sqrt{3^2+3^2}=\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt2$$

Answer (score 0):

if you regard the chords as the axes of a rectangular co-ordinate system, with origin K, then you have shown that the coordinates of the center of the circle, O, must be $(3,3)$. So the distance OK is $3 \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thanks for answering @davidholden but I do not get how O= (3,3) and is it possible without using the coordinate system?

Comment: your Pythagoras argument shows that the distance from the circle center O to any chord $c$ of length 8 cm must be 3 cm. but this distance is just the co-ordinate of O measured from K along a chord perpendicular to $c$. draw a diagram and it should be clear